# Simplexml get path from variable

Tags: variables, path, simplexml

Is there a way to pass the path to a simplexml node as a variable?
This is what I tried:

```
//set the path to the node in a variable
$comp = 'component->structuredBody->component';

echo count($xml->component->structuredBody->component); //=== 13
echo count($xml->$comp); //===0
echo count($xml->{$comp});//===0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), and more specifically SimpleXML's [`xpath()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath). Instead of traversing using PHP's `->` operator, you would traverse using XPath's `/` operator, but otherwise, could achieve exactly the effect you wanted:

```
$comp = 'component[1]/structuredBody[1]/component';
echo count( $xml->xpath($comp) );
```

You might think that this could be simplified to `'component/structuredBody/component'`, but that would find *all possible paths matching the expression* - that is if there are multiple `structuredBody` elements, it will search all of them. That might actually be useful, but it is not equivalent to `$xml->component->structuredBody->component`, which is actually shorthand for `$xml->component[0]->structuredBody[0]->component`.

A few things to note:

- Unlike most operations with SimpleXML, the result is an array, not another SimpleXML object (think of it as a set of search results). It is therefore vital that you check it is not empty before accessing element 0 as an object.
- As you can see in the example above, XPath counts from 1, not 0. I don't know why, but it's caught me out before, so I thought I'd warn you.
- The library SimpleXML is built on supports only XPath 1.0; 
  examples you see online for XPath 2.0 may not work.
- XPath 1.0 has no notion of a "default namespace", and SimpleXML doesn't automatically register namespace prefixes for use in XPath, so if you're working with namespaces, you need to use [`registerXPathNamespace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php).